# Mutithreading in C# queries

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to multithreading in C# . I have a 3D array of size (x)*(y)*(z) and say i want to calculate the average of all the z samples for every (x,y) values. I wish to do that using multithreading (say 2 threads) where i will send half the array of size (x/2)*y*z for processing to thread1 and the other half to thread2.

How to do it? How do I pass and retrieve arguments from individual threads? A code example will be helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend using [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) for this instead of threading this yourself.

It will let you run your query using LINQ syntax, but parallelize it (across all of your cores) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why it makes sense to use something PLINQ (as mentioned by Reed) or Parallel.For as implementing a low-overhead scheduler for distributing jobs over several cpus is a bit challenging.

So if I understood you correctly maybe this could get you started (on my 4 core machine the parallel version is 3 times faster than the single core version):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{

    static void AverageOfZ (
        double[] input, 
        double[] result,
        int x, 
        int y, 
        int z
        )
    {
        Debug.Assert(input.Length == x*y*z);
        Debug.Assert(result.Length == x*y);

        //Replace Parallel with Sequential to compare with non-parallel loop
        //Sequential.For(
        Parallel.For(
            0,
            x*y,
            i =>
                {
                    var begin = i*z;
                    var end = begin + z;
                    var sum = 0.0;

                    for (var iter = begin; iter < end; ++iter)
                    {
                        sum += input[iter];
                    }

                    result[i] = sum/z;
                });

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int X = 64;
        const int Y = 64;
        const int Z = 64;
        const int Repetitions = 40000;

        var random = new Random(19740531);
        var samples = Enumerable.Range(0, X*Y*Z).Select(x => random.NextDouble()).ToArray();
        var result = new double[X*Y];

        var then = DateTime.Now;

        for (var iter = 0; iter < Repetitions; ++iter)
        {
            AverageOfZ(samples, result, X, Y, Z);
        }

        var diff = DateTime.Now - then;
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0} samples processed {1} times in {2} seconds", 
            samples.Length,
            Repetitions,
            diff.TotalSeconds
            );

    }
}

static class Sequential
{
    public static void For(int from, int to, Action<int> action)
    {
        for (var iter = from; iter < to; ++iter)
        {
            action(iter);
        }
    }
}
```

PS. When going for concurrent performance its important to consider how the different cores access memory as its very easy to get disappointing performance otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. But is PLINQ available in .NET 3.5 or versions prior to .NET 4.0? I ask because I am limited to .NET 3.5 because of framework limitations.

Comment: Parallel is an addition to .NET4. Implementing Parallel.For is a bit harder than what one can imagine as it has pretty cool stuff for work stealing of tasks between threads and makes user Win7 user mode threads (lower overhead). However, if you need high-perf parallel computing but doesn't like to write the framework yourself you could write C++ library in VS2010 using PPL (Parallel for c++) and static link the library creating a self contained dll that you then use from .NET35

Answer (score 0):

Dot Net 3.5 and onward introduced many shortcut keywords that abstract away the complexity of things like Parallel for multi threading or Async for Async IO. Unfortunately this also provides no opportunity for understanding whats involved in these tasks. For example a colleague of mine was recently trying to use Async for a login method which returned an authentication token.

Here is the full blown multi threaded sample code for your scenario. to make it more real the sample code pretends that:
X is Longitude
Y is Lattitude
and Z is Rainfall Samples at the coordinates

The sample code also follows the Unit of Work design pattern where Rainfall Samples at each coordinate becomes a work item. It also creates discrete foreground threads instead of using a background threadpool.
Due to the simplicity of the work item and short compute time involved I've split the thread synchronization locks into two locks. one for the work queue and one for the output data.
Note: I have not used any Dot net shortcuts such as Lync so this code should run on Dot Net 2.0 as well.

In real world app development something like whats below would only be needed in complex scenarios such as stream processing of a continuous stream of work items in which case you would also need to implement output data buffers cleared regularly as the threads would effectively run forever.

```
public static class MultiThreadSumRainFall
{
    const int LongitudeSize = 64;
    const int LattitudeSize = 64;
    const int RainFallSamplesSize = 64;
    const int SampleMinValue = 0;
    const int SampleMaxValue = 1000;
    const int ThreadCount = 4;

    public static void SumRainfallAndOutputValues()
    {
        int[][][] SampleData;
        SampleData = GenerateSampleRainfallData();
        for (int Longitude = 0; Longitude < LongitudeSize; Longitude++)
        {
            for (int Lattitude = 0; Lattitude < LattitudeSize; Lattitude++)
            {
                QueueWork(new WorkItem(Longitude, Lattitude, SampleData[Longitude][Lattitude]));
            }
        }
        System.Threading.ThreadStart WorkThreadStart;
        System.Threading.Thread WorkThread;
        List<System.Threading.Thread> RunningThreads;
        WorkThreadStart = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ParallelSum);
        int NumThreads;
        NumThreads = ThreadCount;
        if (ThreadCount < 1)
        {
            NumThreads = 1;
        }
        else if (NumThreads > (Environment.ProcessorCount + 1))
        {
            NumThreads = Environment.ProcessorCount + 1;
        }
        OutputData = new int[LongitudeSize, LattitudeSize];
        RunningThreads = new List<System.Threading.Thread>();
        for (int I = 0; I < NumThreads; I++)
        {
            WorkThread = new System.Threading.Thread(WorkThreadStart);
            WorkThread.Start();
            RunningThreads.Add(WorkThread);
        }
        bool AllThreadsComplete;
        AllThreadsComplete = false;
        while (!AllThreadsComplete)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            AllThreadsComplete = true;
            foreach (System.Threading.Thread WorkerThread in RunningThreads)
            {
                if (WorkerThread.IsAlive)
                {
                    AllThreadsComplete = false;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int Longitude = 0; Longitude < LongitudeSize; Longitude++)
        {
            for (int Lattitude = 0; Lattitude < LattitudeSize; Lattitude++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Concat(OutputData[Longitude, Lattitude], @" "));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    private class WorkItem
    {
        public WorkItem(int _Longitude, int _Lattitude, int[] _RainFallSamples)
        {
            Longitude = _Longitude;
            Lattitude = _Lattitude;
            RainFallSamples = _RainFallSamples;
        }
        public int Longitude { get; set; }
        public int Lattitude { get; set; }
        public int[] RainFallSamples { get; set; }
    }

    public static int[][][] GenerateSampleRainfallData()
    {
        int[][][] Result;
        Random Rnd;
        Rnd = new Random();
        Result = new int[LongitudeSize][][];
        for(int Longitude = 0; Longitude < LongitudeSize; Longitude++)
        {
            Result[Longitude] = new int[LattitudeSize][];
            for (int Lattidude = 0; Lattidude < LattitudeSize; Lattidude++)
            {
                Result[Longitude][Lattidude] = new int[RainFallSamplesSize];
                for (int Sample = 0; Sample < RainFallSamplesSize; Sample++)
                {
                    Result[Longitude][Lattidude][Sample] = Rnd.Next(SampleMinValue, SampleMaxValue);
                }
            }
        }
        return Result;
    }

    private static object SyncRootWorkQueue = new object();
    private static Queue<WorkItem> WorkQueue = new Queue<WorkItem>();
    private static void QueueWork(WorkItem SamplesWorkItem)
    {
        lock(SyncRootWorkQueue)
        {
            WorkQueue.Enqueue(SamplesWorkItem);
        }
    }
    private static WorkItem DeQueueWork()
    {
        WorkItem Samples;
        Samples = null;
        lock (SyncRootWorkQueue)
        {
            if (WorkQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                Samples = WorkQueue.Dequeue();
            }
        }
        return Samples;
    }
    private static int QueueSize()
    {
        lock(SyncRootWorkQueue)
        {
            return WorkQueue.Count;
        }
    }

    private static object SyncRootOutputData = new object();
    private static int[,] OutputData;
    private static void SetOutputData(int Longitude, int Lattitude, int SumSamples)
    {
        lock(SyncRootOutputData)
        {
            OutputData[Longitude, Lattitude] = SumSamples;
        }
    }

    private static void ParallelSum()
    {
        WorkItem SamplesWorkItem;
        int SummedResult;
        SamplesWorkItem = DeQueueWork();
        while (SamplesWorkItem != null)
        {
            SummedResult = 0;
            foreach (int SampleValue in SamplesWorkItem.RainFallSamples)
            {
                SummedResult += SampleValue;
            }
            SetOutputData(SamplesWorkItem.Longitude, SamplesWorkItem.Lattitude, SummedResult);
            SamplesWorkItem = DeQueueWork();
        }
    }
}
```